# Could not create another Distribution certificate, reached the maximum number of available Distribution certificates

Tags: ios, code-signing

when I use this command to generate a iOS distribution certificate:

```
fastlane match adhoc
```

shows this error:

```
[!] Could not create another Distribution certificate, reached the maximum number of available Distribution certificates.
```

I check my certificate repo on the GitHub that only contains development certificate now.
[image]

Why I could not generate a distribution certificate? The certificate only could use in one environment? how to invalid the old development certificat? What should I do to make it work? But now I reinvoke the development certificate still show this error:

[image]

Only have one development cerfificate still tell me: `Could not create another Development certificate, reached the maximum number of available Development certificates`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Util 2021.08.18, the apple only support 3 distribution certificate per development account, to my suprise, the apple did not mention this limit to the developer. this is where I got this information from: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/100611.